# HAXM (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, haxm

I installed Android Studio and I had no problems with that. However, when I tried to run the emulator, it said that Intel HAXM was not installed.

So I found the installer, ran it, and it even though it said my laptop supports it, that it was not enabled. I went, enabled the Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x), but I still got the same message.

I hear something about Hyper-V needs to be disabled, but when I go to Turn Windows features on/off, I cannot find it on that list.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your laptop has AMD processor?

Comment: question lacking laptop specs. windows version.!!

Comment: You need also "hypervisor driver 2.0" to install from "SDK Tools" of Android Studio.